# Spring one-to-many always empty

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have 2 entities `A` & `B`. Both are related via new entity `AB`.

```
public class A {
    // other fields
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "a")
    private AB ab;
}

public class B {
    // other fields
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "b")
    private AB ab;
}

public class AB{
    // more fields
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "a_id")
    private A a;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "b_id")
    private B b;
}
```

Now above code works, but when I try to add a relationship directly from `A` to `B`, my results are always empty.

```
public class A {
    // other fields
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "a")
    private AB ab;

        @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
        private Set<B> b;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps the one-to-many annotation requires a mappedBy attribute (like the others).

Comment: I tried that, but the join query which gets fired always returns empty result

Comment: I suppose you've tried making Set b a joinColumn as well?  More information about the entities in general might help.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you use `@OneToOne` from one side and `@ManyToOne` from the other side.

You should use `@OneToMany` in the class A and B. What is quite logical: If multiple AB can be connected to A, then there should be a collection of ABs in class A.

And after you change those annotations, you can immediately see that the relation between A and B is `@ManyToMany`.